# SharePoint App DOM Manipulation and Deployment

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

I've got some issues with development and deployment of a sharepoint app. The App is going to be an App Part in a SharePoint site.

One issue is, that the app (provider hosted) is not high trusted, although I went through the msdn tutorial how to create a high trusted app (with certificate etc.) Everytime I deploy the app, I get the error: The specified application identifier is invalid or does not exist.

The second issue is, that the App uses JavaScript to manipulate the DOM. The problem is, that I can only manipulate the DOM of the App Part. But I want to manipulate the DOM of the SharePoint site itself, and all DOMs laying in it (all other Web or App Parts included in the Site).

Is this possible?

For example, in the App I want to manipulate the Menu of the SharePoint Site this way:

```
document.getElementById("zz15_RootAspMenu"). do something
```

This way I could add Menu-points. But I have no access to zz15_RootAspMenu because its in the outer DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about the former question, but to the latter, can you add your JS to it's own JS file and access it as a reference via your SharePoint MasterPage?

Comment: If I create a new .js File in the Scripts-section, I can access this file, yes. (This was your question?). But I can't access the Components of the SharePoint Page via ID out of the App. That's the problem.